# How to disable swipe panel only in specific page in framework7?

Tags: html-framework-7

I am a newbie to framework7 and I am using the swipe panel for listing the options. But in the index and some pages I don't want the slide to open. I have enabled the panel with swipe left like this:

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    material: isAndroid ? true : false,
    template7Pages: true
    swipePanel : 'left'
});
```

Is there any option to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to do the same and I solved it by setting false the swipePanel param in the page I wanted to disable it, for example:

```
appName.onPageInit('screenName', function (page) {
    appName.params.swipePanel = false;
});
```

Comment: With this method, swipePanel will be disable in the all app after visiting this page, no?

Comment: Yes, but you can re enable it where you need it.

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem @OIS?

Comment: @Skyboy Could not disable the swipe left from the "logged in page" to the "login page". In the end I disabled the swipe left completely.

Comment: i too have to disable swipe left completely.. :(

Answer (score 0):

in my case, all pages having a init.js trigged when navigates to. Then, i put this code bellow in pages who i want to display menu with swipe:

myApp.params.swipePanel = 'left';

in the others pages, i put this next code for block the swipe:

myApp.params.swipePanel = false;

p.s. i using the v1.framework7, i dont testing in the new version of

Answer (score 0):

Please use below config in the specific page's PageOninit event.

**app.panel.disableSwipe(side)**- disable swipes for panel (swipe-to-close and swipe-to-open)

side - string. Panel to disable swipe actions on